# ¿Por qué mi notebook no bootea en el disco duro?

Tags: windows10

Mi problema es el siguiente, ya instalé el sistema operativo (**windows 10**) en formato UEFI en el disco duro desde una memoria, pero al completarse la acción si la memoria esta colocada, vuelve a instalar el sistema operativo, sino es así entonces sale el error:

```
Error: Instale el sistema operativo en el disco duro (3FO)
```

Comment: Esta pregunta no se encuentra en los [tópicos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) de [es.so].

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es una pregunta sobre programación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero hay que ver si en la bios se reconoce el disco duro, oprime la tecla f2 o f10  o supr, luego verificar que el arranque seguro este activado, y que arranque en modo UEFI, si esta en modo heredado no va a funcionar porque al tabla de particiones que instala windows 10 no permite arrancar el sistema, si esto no funciona cambiar el cd de instalacion de windows 10, tambien seria bueno hacer un chequeo del estado del disco duro comprobando los sectores.

Comment: saludos y gracias por la ayuda, pero esta pregunta no esta dentro del marco de publicaciones permitidas aclaradas en este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic por tanto no debería ser respondida